# Vertical tearing in PDFs with Microsoft Edge Chromium and Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, microsoft-edge

When I scroll through a PDF in both Chrome and the new Chromium-based Edge browser, horizontal tearing appears randomly, like in the central line of this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of a teared line.]

If I scroll the affected line out of the screen then back, or if I select then un-select it, it will be rendered correctly again. This has been happening to me for years on two different laptops, and only on Windows.

Sometimes this is just distracting, sometimes it makes a line hard to read.

Is this a known bug, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the PDF reader feature within Chrome.  Does the EdgeHTML version of Edge exhibit this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound no, only the new Edge does. I also think it’s a bug in Chrome, but I haven’t found anything about it even though it has existed for years on my machines. I wanted to make sure it wasn’t known before reporting it.

Comment: Is this any PDF?  Can you try different versions of Chrome?

Comment: @Ramhound It happens on all kinds of PDF, and I've tested most versions of Chrome in the last few years.